# How to slice an array based on values 0 and nonzero

Tags: python, numpy

Assume, that we have an array:

```
a=[0 0 0 1 3 5 0 0 0 5 3 2 1 5 3 1 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 0 0 0 4 1 4 9 8 0]
```

How to divide it, removing 0, and make them smaller?

The result should be:

```
b=[1 3 5] ; c=[5 3 2 1 5 3 1 4] ; d=[1 2] ; e=[4 1 4 9 8]
```

I was thinking about moving window, is it the right way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using external modules, you could perhaps do something like:

```
a=[0,0,0,1,3,5,0,0,0,5,3,2,1,5,3,1,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,0,0,0,4,1,4,9,8,0]

lst=[[]]
for num in a:
    if not num and lst[-1]:
        lst.append([])
    elif num:
        lst[-1].append(num)
if not lst[-1]:
    lst.pop()
```

This would step through your list 'a', creating new list when it encounters a zero, and appending the current number where it is not zero.

Answer (score 0):

```
a=[0,0,0,1,3,5,0,0,0,5,3,2,1,5,3,1,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,0,0,0,4,1,4,9,8,0]
list1 = [[]]
list2 = []
for i in a:
    if i!=0:
        list1[-1].append(i)
    else:
        list1.append([])
for i in list1:
    if i != []:
        list2.append(i)
print(list2)
```